# What's the linq version of a multiple field group by count?

Tags: linq, .net-3.5

SQL query:

```
select ApplicationNumber,pri_indicator,count(*) from customer
group by ApplicationNumber,pri_indicator
```

How do I do this in LINQ?

I see plenty of results on using a simple group by to count a single field, but can't seem to find any or figure out how to do multiple fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just:

```
var query = from customer in db.Customers
            group customer by 
                 new { customer.ApplicationNumber, customer.PriIndicator }
                 into grouped
            select new { grouped.Key.ApplicationNumber,
                         grouped.Key.PriIndicator,
                         Count = grouped.Count() };
```

should work, I think.

Comment: very nice, how would you attack a having count(*)>1?

Comment: After the "into grouped" line, add where grouped.Count() > 1